# Why is my StringSet not saved to SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm building an app that uses Google Places Api.  Right now, when the user picks a place, the place name is added to a StringSet, which is then (supposed to be) saved to SharedPreferences.  However, every time I restart the app, SharedPreferences is cleared.  How do I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST;
ListView placeListView;
ArrayList<String> placeArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    placeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placeListView);
    placeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeArrayList);
    placeListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
           builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    pickPlace();


        }
    });
}

public void pickPlace(){

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            placeArrayList.add((String) place.getName());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            set.addAll(placeArrayList);
            editor.putStringSet("key", set);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("key", set).apply();
           Log.e("places", String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getStringSet("key", null)));
//Retrieve the values




        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

Comment: You don't have to use editor.putStringSet("key", set); Just use 
            sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("key", set).apply();

Comment: It still doesn't save though